# Ant - how to get all files' name in a specific folder

Tags: ant

Here is my Ant script for generating jar package. I have bunch of jar packages for manifest Class-Path attribute, they are all in an specific folder.

I don't want to hard code it, how can I get them automatically?

```
<jar jarfile="${client_deploy_dir}/HelloWorld.jar"
     basedir="${client_work_dir}/compiled">
   <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="HelloWorld.Main"/>
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="???"/>
   </manifest>
</jar>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, use manifestclasspath task. The **jarfile** attribute is used to create relative links to the jars contained in the fileset.

```
<manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${client_work_dir}/HelloWorld.jar">
  <classpath>
    <fileset name="" dir="${client_work_dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</manifestclasspath>

<jar jarfile="${client_deploy_dir}/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="${client_work_dir}/compiled">
    <manifest>
         <attribute name="Main-Class" value="HelloWorld.Main"/>
         <attribute name="Class-Path" value=""${jar.classpath}"/>
      </manifest>
   </jar>
```

Comment: While testing this solution on Ant 1.9.4 I get the error "manifestclasspath doesn't support the nested "fileset" element.".

Comment: @Sèb Thx, my bad. I've corrected the example to include the "classpath" tags.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ant [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task.  You can use this to expand an existing fileset into a list of files.

Comment: Yes, pathconvert does help me. I set attribute pathsep="${line.separator}lib/".

Comment: No need for pathconvert. The manifestclasspath task is capable of generating relative links to the eventual jarfile