# Creating a JAR file which contains other library files

Tags: jar, classpath, executable, java

I want to create one executable [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file which contains other JAR libraries. But when I execute the JAR, it gives an error of class path problem.

How do I solve the class-path problem?

Comment: *"I want to create one executable Jar which contains other jar libraries"*  What you want is less important than what works.  Deploying multiple Jars with [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) or another type of installer has been seen to work well on many occasions.

Comment: Duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424761/java-packaging-building-common-techniques-jar-file-specifically/5424847#5424847

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can try it like this;

Here is a simple example for you question. First, we assume we have a project directory like `D:\javademo`. In this working directory we then create a main class **HelloWorld.java** and thtat contains our other JAR files, like `commons-lang.jar`. Now, we must archive our main classes HelloWorld and commons-lang.jar into test.jar file.

First we must edit our manifest file so that we can specify our class-path and main-class
like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Created-By: tony example
Class-Path: test.jar commons-lang.jar
Main-Class: org.tony.java.HelloWorld
```

We named this file `test.mf`. Now we use the `jar` command to generate our JAR file like this:

```
jar -cvfm test.jar test.mf -C ./ .
```

Then it will generate the JAR file `test.jar`. You can use this command to run this main class using java command:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

That is my solution. I hope it give you something helpful...

Comment: Thank you so much i confused to how can to add library dependencies to jar file

Comment: this appears to just set the classpath, not bundle .jars into a .jar

Answer (score 0):

You should use third-party libraries for it. For example, [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net). You'll have to build the final JAR file using the OneJar tool (like [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) task) instead of standard [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment)'s tools.

On running such a JAR file, OneJar's service class is launched instead of yours. This class then loads JAR files packed inside, as well as your classes, and run your main class.

There are similar questions and answers already. For example: Stack Overflow question *[Easiest way to merge a release into one JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/java-easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file)*.

Comment: I tried many times before I post this, but still not working.