# Combining jars for multi modules maven project in a single jar

Tags: maven, executable-jar, maven-module

I have a parent maven project that includes some child projects and a build/assembly project. The structure looks like this

```
ParentProj
    + pom.xml 
    + ChildProj1
        ++   pom.xml
    + ChildProj2
     ++   pom.xml
    + buildProj
     ++   pom.xml
```

I want to create an executable jar in the build project, or project that contains all child project jars. Basically the final result should be a jar that includes all child project jars in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project buildProj should have the other child projects declared as dependencies, you could then configure the maven assembly plugin to use the predefined descriptor jar-with-dependencies which create a jar that contains the dependencies.

- [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven).
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html

EDIT
If you wish to add the dependencies jar in your jar, you could use something like onejar:

- [Creating a JAR file which contains other library files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890747/creating-a-jar-file-which-contains-the-other-library-files)
- http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

There is a maven plugin for this tool: https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/

Comment: is there a way to include all dependencies as jars under lib folder inside the build jar. instead of deflating everything in the build jar

Comment: ended up using this solution which is kind of mix of things but works https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/tree/master/ch07