# Execute JAR from lib directory

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have the "SomeJarA.jar" with the followiung structure:

```
SomeJarA
|
|--lib/SomeJarB.jar
|--com/.../SomeClass.class
```

Im trying to execute the "SomeJarB.jar" in "SomeClass.java" using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar SomeJarB.jar");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if there's a way to achieve this, it is going to be a tricky and highly unsupported arrangement. I'll look around for some supporting documentation, but I'm inclined to say "No."

This related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890747/creating-a-jar-file-which-contains-the-other-library-files) might help, though.

EDIT: Found the reference I wanted. It's [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html). Specifically, there's a note which says, "The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, ***not JAR files within the JAR file*** or classes accessible over internet protocols."

Answer (score 0):

This is from user @Tezar and Question [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)

```
You can use "Class-Path" in your manifest file.

For example:

Create manifest file MANIFEST.MF

    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Created-By: Bundle
    Class-Path: ./custom_lib.jar
    Main-Class: YourMainClass

Compile all your classes and run
jar cfm Testing.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class custom_lib.jar

c stands for create archive f indicates that you want to specify file v
is for verbose input m means that we will pass custom manifest file

Be sure that you included lib in jar package. You should be able to run
jar in the normal way.

based on: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things6/
```

See the linked Question.  It seems like the sanest method for jars in jars and avoids third-party class loaders.  If you feel like upvoting, go to Tezar's answer and upvote that entry, not this one, as this is just a copy.