# Setting Class-Path in Ant build script

Tags: java, ant, build, classpath

I'm trying to build my console application and I'm using Ant to build it. I can run my application in Eclipse, but when I try to run it from jar that I get - the ClassNotFoundException:  is thrown.  is in one of jars, that I use for my application. Here is a part of build.xml where I create manifest:

```
<manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.package.Reporter" />
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
        lib/commons-logging-api.jar
        ...lot of jars...
        lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar" />
</manifest>
```

The required class is in commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
And here is how I set up classpath for compiling, that is fine:

```
<path id="libs.dir">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>
```

**UPD**: Should I put jars with libs to my jar? Now I'm putting them to "lib" directory of my jar. So myjar.jar contains package with my classes, META-INF directory and lib directory.

Comment: Compile time is not the same as runtime. How are you trying to run your application?

Comment: Yes. I understend this. I'm trying to run it with `java -jar <jarname>.jar`

Comment: So, do you want to know how to run your application from a command line having some external dependencies?

Comment: Putting dependent jars in a lib or META-INF/lib folder of a jar will not work. It only works for war or ear archives because it's art of the JEE spec, and JEE containers are able to construct a classpath from there. Under normal circumstances, you have to explicitly set a classpath that includes these separate jars along with you jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max, you can't insert jar libs into jar, assuming normal usage. Either you don't have to specify them manually at runtime as Romski suggested. When invoking `java -jar myjar.jar` it should locate all your jars provided that they are located in the `lib` directory. `lib` directory must be in the same directory that jar resides in. Doesn't matter if you call `java` executable directly or through ant `java` task.

Note that the current directory doesn't matter only the relation between the jar and the `lib`.

Now being overly explicit. Perform sanity test as follows: create a new `tmp` directory and copy files to it:

```
tmp/myjar.jar
tmp/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
```

Run `java -jar tmp/myjar.jar`

Edit: now I see I just wrote the same what is in [Oracle jar tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html). But I also made tests myself with a relative directory. I also see dozens of stackoverflow questions searching for *jar in jar* so please first search SO, then ask.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the path like this.

```
 <path id="libs.dir">
   <fileset dir="./lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
 </path>
```

Comment: that didn`t help. But I can compile my application with no problems. Seems like something wrong with classpath when I run the app

Answer (score 0):

You need the manifestclasspath task.

Example:

- [Ant - how to get all files' name in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796824/ant-how-to-get-all-files-name-in-a-specific-folder/3797767#3797767)